# ¿Como hacer que input se adapten dentro de un panel que esta en col-md-6?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

Les explico, tengo una ventana modal que tiene 3 panel, el primero esta en una row y tiene col-md-12, todo bien alli.

el segundo y tercer panel estan en una row con col-md-6 respectivamente.

Todo bien hasta alli, mi problema es cuando cambio de tamaño la pantalla, ya que los input que estan dentro de los panel se salen de su contenedor, en este caso el panel.

Dejo 3 imagenes ilustrativas para que puedan verlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Comportamiendo no deseado]

[image: Comportamiento No deseado]

```js
$('#dataUpdate').modal('show');
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 3px 2% 2% 2%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  min-height: 95%;
}

#ide {
  background-color: #E8F9FF;
}

#com1 {
  background: #25995B;
  color: white;
}

#com2 {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}

#ad1 {
  background: #25995B;
  color: white;
}

#ad2 {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="actualizarDatos">
  <div class="modal fade" id="dataUpdate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 ng-hide="newUser">Detalles Del Cajero</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
            <li class="active"><a href="#generales" data-toggle="tab">Generales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tecnicos" data-toggle="tab">Técnicos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#disponibilidad" data-toggle="tab">Disponibilidad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#visa" data-toggle="tab">VISA</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 2em;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="generales">
              <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">


                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Identificacion</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="ide">


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label for="codigo">Codigo ATM</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="codigo" type="text" name="codigo">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreCorto" type="text">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre Largo</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Localidad:</label>



                              <select name="localidad" class="form-control input-sm">    

                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
               
               </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Tipo De Ubicacion:</label>



                              <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
          
               </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Tipo De Localidad:</label>



                              <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
  

               </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre Largo</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                      <div class="panel-heading" id="com1">Comunicaciones</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="com2">

                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Proveedor</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <?php
                $sql = 'SELECT ID_PLATAFORMA,DESC_PLATAFORMA FROM PLATAFORMA';
                $result =  sqlsrv_query($_conn, $sql)
                ?>

                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
              

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Dirección IP</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Gateway</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Subnet Mask</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                      <div class="panel-heading" id="ad1">Adicional</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="ad2">
                        <div class="container">


                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Red Del Cajero</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">


                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
            

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>


                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo De ATM</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                             

                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
            
                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado Del ATM</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">


                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
        

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Producción</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                              <input style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                          </div>



                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>




              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tecnicos">
              <h1>h</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="disponibilidad">
              <h1>hhh</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="visa">
              <h1>hhhj</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Actualizar datos</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

En este snippet no se porque no sale el modal con un width del 95%, en la prueba que realizo en mi pc si sale todo el width, aqui no puedo, si alguien puede decirme como editarlo para que prueben de la mejor manera, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Luis Fernando tu problema es el mal uso de la clase "container", deberias haber usado la clase "col-sm-12" en Cada panel(Comunicaciones y Adicional) y despues cada elemento como el label y el input poner "col-sm-6" y te ocuparan el 100% del contenedor padre.
Te falto tambien la clase row en direccion IP.
Espero haberte ayudado!.
Te dejo mas informacion del sistema de rejilla de boostrap: https://ajgallego.gitbooks.io/bootstrap-3/content/capitulo_rejilla.html

```js
$('#dataUpdate').modal('show');
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 3px 2% 2% 2%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  min-height: 95%;
}

#ide {
  background-color: #E8F9FF;
}

#com1 {
  background: #25995B;
  color: white;
}

#com2 {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}

#ad1 {
  background: #25995B;
  color: white;
}

#ad2 {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="actualizarDatos">
  <div class="modal fade" id="dataUpdate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 ng-hide="newUser">Detalles Del Cajero</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
            <li class="active"><a href="#generales" data-toggle="tab">Generales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tecnicos" data-toggle="tab">Técnicos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#disponibilidad" data-toggle="tab">Disponibilidad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#visa" data-toggle="tab">VISA</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 2em;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="generales">
              <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">


                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Identificacion</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="ide">


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label for="codigo">Codigo ATM</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="codigo" type="text" name="codigo">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreCorto" type="text">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre Largo</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Localidad:</label>



                              <select name="localidad" class="form-control input-sm">    

                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
               
               </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Tipo De Ubicacion:</label>



                              <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
          
               </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <label for="dato1">Tipo De Localidad:</label>



                              <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                 <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
  

               </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre Largo</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                      <div class="panel-heading" id="com1">Comunicaciones</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="com2">

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Proveedor</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <?php
                $sql = 'SELECT ID_PLATAFORMA,DESC_PLATAFORMA FROM PLATAFORMA';
                $result =  sqlsrv_query($_conn, $sql)
                ?>

                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    


                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
              

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Dirección IP</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Gateway</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Subnet Mask</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                      <div class="panel-heading" id="ad1">Adicional</div>
                      <div class="panel-body" id="ad2">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">


                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Red Del Cajero</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">


                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
            

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>


                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Tipo De ATM</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             

                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
            
                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Estado Del ATM</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">


                                <select name="plataforma" class="form-control input-sm">    

                  <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_PLATAFORMA'] ?> " ></option>
        

                </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Producción</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" id="nombre" name="nombreLargo" type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                          </div>



                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>




              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tecnicos">
              <h1>h</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="disponibilidad">
              <h1>hhh</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="visa">
              <h1>hhhj</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Actualizar datos</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```